# Will my app crash when iOS 9.3 comes out?

Tags: ios, swift

A while back, I remember putting several of my apps on to my iPhone. However, once I upgraded my phone's software, none of my apps worked. I had to reinstall them with the new version of Xcode. I recently published an app, and I'm not sure if it'll crash when iOS 9.3 comes out. I would not like that to happen, and I want to know what I can do to fix it. My Xcode project currently allows all softwares about 9.0.

Edit
So people were confused what I was talking about. Here is what happened
I had Xcode 7.0.1 or something and my phone was 9.0 My apps that I built into my phone worked fine
When I upgraded my iPhone software, my apps crashed. They did not open.

I published an app into the App Store
I was wondering if my app would crash when iOS 9.3
Hope that is more specific.

Edit:
It was fine

Comment: have u check y was ur app wasnt working??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only with that information is hard to know.

However, it is rare to crash between .X versions, and even between iOS8 and iOS9 it was rare to crash with **older** versions.  Usualy older APIs are well supported.

If you want to be sure you can always [install the beta](https://developer.apple.com/ios/download/).